# Unable to import .csv into mongodb using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, csv, import, mongoimport

I am doing some tests to see how I can import a simple .csv file into mongodb but it mongodb keeps returning "0 objects imported. Here are my steps:

1) create a simple .csv file named "a4.csv" in mongodb/bin with 4 columns and 6 records:

```
Model       Make    Price   Mileage
audi        a5      500     500
mercedes    cla     333     434
ford        fusion  555     500
mazda       miata   222     434
nissan      370z    111     500
porsche     cayenne 333     434
```

2) Run import command:

```
./mongoimport -d test -c cars --type csv --file a4.csv --headerline
```

Output:

```
tins-MBP:bin tinzors$ ./mongoimport -d test -c cars --type csv --file a4.csv --headerline
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2015-02-11T12:23:11.656-0500 imported 0 objects
```

There's no error anything. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Fyi you can [add mongo binaries to $PATH](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/#ensure-the-location-of-the-binaries-is-in-the-path-variable), `export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH`, then you can run mongoimport command from anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is in `csv` file format

**a4.csv** file placed in mongodb bin folder

```
Model,Make,Price,Mileage
audi,a5,500,500
mercedes,cla,333,434
ford,fusion,555,500
mazda,miata,222,434
nissan,370z,111,500
porsche,cayenne,333,434
```

then

`mongoimport -d test -c cars --type csv --file a4.csv --headerline`

**Output**

`D:\MongoDB\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongoimport -d test -c cars --type csv --file a4.csv --headerline
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2015-02-11T23:15:20.631+0530 imported 6 objects`

```
> db.cars.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54db93a60259aeb2c15b851d"), "Model" : "audi", "Make" : "a5", "Price" : 500, "Mileage" : 500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54db93a60259aeb2c15b851e"), "Model" : "mercedes", "Make" : "cla", "Price" : 333, "Mileage" : 434 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54db93a60259aeb2c15b851f"), "Model" : "ford", "Make" : "fusion", "Price" : 555, "Mileage" : 500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54db93a60259aeb2c15b8520"), "Model" : "mazda", "Make" : "miata", "Price" : 222, "Mileage" : 434 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54db93a60259aeb2c15b8521"), "Model" : "nissan", "Make" : "370z", "Price" : 111, "Mileage" : 500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54db93a60259aeb2c15b8522"), "Model" : "porsche", "Make" : "cayenne", "Price" : 333, "Mileage" : 434 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response - could you explain to me what the difference is between your method and my method? Or should I fix the .csv file somehow?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi , fix the `csv` file and check once. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to import all the records from the csv into just 1 object instead of 1 object per record?

Comment: when I tried to do the same thing mongoimport -d test -c cars --type csv --file cars.csv           It's giving me an error saying : [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15

Answer (score 2):

So I THINK part of the issue is I created the file in Excel then saved it as a .csv file that that might have corrupted the file somehow. So I opened the original .csv file in a text editor (Sublime), copied the data into a brand new Sublime document and re-saved it as .csv and it worked!